# Remote JNDI access to a single resource in TomEE

Tags: tomcat7, jndi, apache-tomee

I'm trying to set an object into JNDI and then get remote access to it. I'm using TomEE 1.6.0. I'm setting a sinple string using an servlet like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    try
    {
        Context ctx=new InitialContext();
        ctx.bind("myKey","MY STRING");
    }
    catch(NamingException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After running and invoke this servlet, I try to get remote access through JNDI using this standalone main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Context ctx = getContext();
    String nom = (String)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/nombre");

    System.out.println(nom);
}

private static Context getContext() throws Exception
{
    Hashtable<String,String> t = new Hashtable<>(); 
    t.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    t.put("java.naming.provider.url","http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomee/ejb");

    return new InitialContext(t);
}
```

But it throws an NameNotFoundException like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: /comp/env/nombre does not exist in the system.  Check that the app was successfully deployed.
    at org.apache.openejb.client.JNDIContext.lookup(JNDIContext.java:319)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at demo.TestJNDI.main(TestJNDI.java:13)
```

So, my question are two:

1 - How can I know the default JNDI name which is using TomEE to publish this string?
2 - How can I set this string into any XML file instead the servlet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect to do but remote context is mainly an ejb/resource one. comp/env is clearly local to the application

Comment: Hi, what I want is difine an object by declaring it in some XML like tomee.xml or any other and then can get access to this object throught JNDI Context. I.e: in tomee.xml declare: <resource name="myobject" class-type="java.lang.String" />. After this, in a standalone main get access to myobject giving it's jndi name. Thanks!